# Open multiple files and assign to individual variables using R

Tags: r

I have a 100 text files with matrices which I want to open using R - the read.table() command can be used for that.
I cant figure out how to assign these files to separate variable names so that I can carry out operations on the matrices.
I am trying to use the for loop but keep getting error messages.
I hope somebody can help me out with this...

Comment: incidentally, the answer here might be helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593001/how-to-upload-a-folder-consisting-of-folders-in-r-for-windows-i-am-uploading-v/15593645#15593645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 100 files, it may make more sense to simply keep them in one neat list.

```
  # Get the list of files
  #----------------------------#
    folder <- "path/to/files"
    fileList <- dir(folder, recursive=TRUE)  # grep through these, if you are not loading them all

    # use platform appropriate separator
    files <- paste(folder, fileList, sep=.Platform$file.sep)


  # Read them in
  #----------------------------#
    myMatrices <- lapply(files, read.table)
```

Then access via, eg,  `myMatrices[[37]]`  or using `lapply`

Comment: @user2203793, you need to use double-brackets.  Take a look at the difference between `myMatricies[1]` and `myMatricies[[1]]`.  The latter is a matrix and the former is a list containing only one element, that element is a matrix.  `+` does not make sense for lists, but it does for matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easer to just use list.files?

For example:

```
files <- list.files(directory/path, pattern= "regexp.if.needed")
```

And then you could access each element by calling files[1], files[2], etc. This would allow you to pull out either all the files in a directory, or just the ones that matched a regular expression.