# Parsing issue, unexpected character when loading a folder

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593001/how-to-upload-a-folder-consisting-of-folders-in-r-for-windows-i-am-uploading-v) to load in a folder of **Excel Files**:

```
# Get the list of files
#----------------------------#
  folder <- "path/to/files"
  fileList <- dir(folder, recursive=TRUE)  # grep through these, if you are not loading them all

  # use platform appropriate separator
  files <- paste(folder, fileList, sep=.Platform$file.sep)
```

So far, so good.

```
# Load them in
#----------------------------#
  # Method 1:
  invisible(sapply(files, source, local=TRUE))

  #-- OR --#

  # Method 2:
  sapply(files, function(f) eval(parse(text=f)))
```

But the source function (Method 1) gives me the error:

```
Error in source("C:/Users/Username/filename.xlsx") : 
  C:/Users/filename :1:3: unexpected input
1: PK
      ^
```

For method 2 get the error:

```
Error in parse(text = f) : <text>:1:3: unexpected '/'
1: C:/
      ^
```

EDIT: I tried circumventing the issue by setting the working directory to the directory of the folder, but that did not help.

Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT 2: It works when doing the following:

[How can I read multiple (excel) files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/how-can-i-read-multiple-excel-files-into-r)

```
setwd("...")
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

Comment: hey @Tom, try to use this: `dir(folder, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) `, it will remove the need of the following `paste`

Comment: also... your first error is caused by `source("C:/Users/Username/filename.xlsx")`, shouldn't you use `source` just to run R script files? Try with this: try this: `dir(folder, recursive=TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".R$")`

Comment: @Edo The first error changes when doing that: `Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection` Second error stays the same. Could there be anything wrong with the naming of the file or the filepath (undesirable characters?) EDIT: for both of your comments

Comment: have you tried my second suggestion too?

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion gives me an empty `fileList`.

Comment: But wait, Edo, are you saying that I cannot load Excel files this way? Because the folder only has Excel files.. That is I guess also why your second comment returns an empty list.

Comment: Exactly. `source` is to run external R code. If you need to load Excel files, try with one of this libraries: `readxl` (probably what you are looking for), `openxlsx`, `tidyxl` (this one is the most complicated but the best if your excel files are rather messy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to provide a proper answer outside of the comment section...

- If your target is to read many Excel files, you shouldn't use `source`.
- `source` is dedicated to run external R code.
- If you need to read many Excel files you can use the following code and the support of one of these libraries: `readxl`, `openxlsx`, `tidyxl` (with `unpivotr`).

```
filelist <- dir(folder, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".xlsx$|.xls$", ignore.case = TRUE) 
l_df <- lapply(filelist, readxl::read_excel)
```

Note that we are using `dir` to list the full paths (`full.names = TRUE`) of all the files that ends with `.xlsx`, `.xls` (`pattern = ".xlsx$|.xls$"`), `.XLSX`, `.XLS` (`ignore.case = TRUE`) in the folder `folder` and all its subfolders (`recursive = TRUE`).

---

`readxl` is integrated with `tidyverse`. It is pretty easy to use. It is most likely what you're looking for.

Personally, I advice to use `openxlsx` if you need to write (rather than read) customized Excel files with many specific features.

`tidyxl` is the best package I've seen to read Excel files, but it may be rather complicated to use. However, it's really careful in the types preservation.
With the support of `unpivotr` it allows you to handle complicated Excel structures.
For example, when you find multiple headers and multiple left index columns.